# 'operator=' in '((library*)this)->library::database[bookcode] = -1'|

Tags: c++

i cant understand the error. why i cant use the operator to delete my entry? help me doing this. this is my book entry class,

```
class bookEntry{
public:
    int code;
    int copies;
    char name[30];
    char author[30];
};
```

and this is my class library

```
class library{
public:
    int numBooks;
    bookEntry database[MAX], tempdatabase[MAX];

    library(){
        numBooks = 0;
    }
    void insertBook( int bookcode, char bookName[], char author[], int bookcopies );
    void deleteBook(int bookcode);
    void search( int bookcode);
    void displayBook( );
    void edit(int bookcode);
    void editname(int numBooks);
    void editauthor(int numBooks);
    void editcopies(int numBooks);

};
```

and this is my void function of delete the entry,

```
void library::deleteBook(int bookcode)

  {
    system("cls");

   cout<<endl;

   cout<<"Enter A Code of a Book To Delete That Entry  ";

   cin>>bookcode;

   cout<<endl;
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<=numBooks-1;i++)

   {
    if (bookcode==database[i].code)
    {
            database[bookcode]=-1;
            cout<<"Book Successfully Deleted...!!"<<endl;
    }


    else

    {
     cout<<"Book not found...!!!"<<endl;
    }

     }
     getch();
  }
```

this is the line where im getting the error,

```
database[bookcode]=-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`database[bookcode]` is a `bookEntry`.

You can't assign an `int` to a class instance.

You can assign a default instance like this:

```
database[bookcode] = bookEntry();
```

This works if your `bookEntry` constructor constructs an empty entry (whatever that means).

Comment: then what should i do to delete the selected entry

Comment: Nothing. You can't "delete" array elements. You will have to be clearer about your goals.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete your entry because you have used a fixed-size array. In fact, you always have `MAX` entries, even if they don't contain any valid data yet.

Either you need to store some kind of flag (either inside the entry or in another array or another method) about which positions are valid, or use a data structure which is not of fixed size, such as `std::vector` or `std::list`. Then you can store any number of books you like, not limited by some arbitrary maximum.

I also suggest you use `std::string` to store the book and author names. How many books can you find with names more than 29 characters in length? Do you not want to support these in your system?

Comment: im a noob in c++ programming please help me on this. i dont know how to use the std::vector and std::list .pease help me on this